# Make email appear in multiple folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

I would like to have an email appear in multiple folders in my outlook. Note that I do NOT want a copy of the email in each folder. Here is my situation -

I have one rule that places all emails directly to me in one folder, and another rule that moves emails from my team to a different folder. However if the email is from my team AND to me it is only moved into my from team folder. How can I have the email show up in both folders without making a copy?

Comment: I know of no way to do this.  I have serious doubts its even possible in Outlook

Comment: Search Folders.

Comment: I don't think its possible either, that's why I'm asking :)

Answer (score 4):

A good tool for this is [Search Folders](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2011/02/07/create-search-folders-in-outlook-2010.aspx).

> If you find yourself scouring your Inbox and various Outlook folders
>   for specific types of mails, there is an easier way. You can create
>   Search Folders for all sorts of common tasks, and then they'll just be
>   a click away!

[image]

It does not copy the messages into the folder, it simply creates a way to find, organize and view them.

Comment: Its not ideal, but I guess its not too bad either.

Comment: This is the best you can get. For example, in Gmail their "labels" are not more than just saved searches (search folders in Outlook).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac and are willing to use a specific email client to solve this, then give [AirMail](https://airmailapp.com)* a try.

AirMail for Mac somehow does this. I cannot explain how it is implemented, but by using their software I am able to add the same email to multiple folders by using their *labels*. I have verified this on Outlook.com where the email subsequently can be found in the related folders.

**I am not affiliated with this software in any way other than being a regular user.*